# I am new to python and I am trying to build a simple Tic-Tac-Tock game.When I am taking input from user it goes to infinity loop

Tags: python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

```py
def player_input():
    player1=''
    player2=''
    while player1 != "X" or player1 !="O":
        player1=input('Choose from X or O').upper()

    if player1=='X':
        player2 = 'O'
        return (player1,player2)
    elif player1=='O':
        player2='X'
        return (player1,player2)
```

When I am running it is going to infinity loop. But,when I am changing my while loop to `while not(player1 =="X" or player1=="O")` my code is running fine. So can someone explain the difference between my both while loop?

Comment: You might want to use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) for that or look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `player1 != "X" or player1 !="O"`: This is a tautology (i.e. it is always `True`). Think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is wrong, you basically want to be in the while loop until the user enters either X or O. Thus, this means:

```
not (player1 == "X" or player1 =="O")
```

This might be a bit confusing specially if you are not familiar with boolean algebra. Basically you have the following:

`X and Y`, so `not (X and Y)` is logically equivalent to `not X or not Y`. In your case you have:

```
not (player1 == "X" or player1 =="O")
```

which is logically equivalent to:

```
player1 != "X" and player1 != "O"
```

If you want to know more about this, you can read about [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)